# Why am I getting a memory leak here? BFS on a graph of strings in C

Tags: c, struct

with the following code I'm getting a memory leak.  This is supposed to do a BFS through a graph of strings in C, and I'm leaking memory even though I think I'm freeing everything after I use it.  From the debugging I've tried to do, I can't seem to find a problem.  It seems to be skipping over some lines in my code, specifically lines 197 and 199. No clue why, any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct adjlistnode {
    char dest[100];
    struct adjlistnode* next;
};

struct adjlist {
    struct adjlistnode* head;
};

struct Graph {
    int vertices;
    struct adjlist* array;
    int* visited;
};

struct queue {
    int items[1000];
    int front;
    int rear;
};

struct Graph* creategraph(int x) {
    struct Graph* graph = malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->vertices = x;

    graph->array = malloc(graph->vertices * sizeof(struct adjlist));
    graph->visited = malloc(graph->vertices * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        graph->array[i].head = NULL;
        graph->visited[i] = 0;
    }
    return graph;
}

struct adjlistnode* makenode(char name[]) {
    struct adjlistnode* newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct adjlistnode));
    strcpy(newnode->dest, name);
    newnode->next = 0;

    return newnode; 
}

struct queue* createqueue() {
    struct queue* queue = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    queue->front = -1;
    queue->rear = -1;
    return queue;
}

int isEmpty(struct queue* q) {
    printf("in isEmpty\n");
  if (q->rear == -1)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

void enqueue(struct queue* q, int value, int size) {
    printf("in enqueue\n");
  if (q->rear == size - 1) {
    printf("\nQueue is Full!!");
    return;
  } else {
    if (q->front == -1)
      q->front = 0;
    q->rear++;
    q->items[q->rear] = value;
  }
}

int dequeue(struct queue* q) {
    printf("in dequeue\n");
  int item;
  if (isEmpty(q)) {
    printf("Queue is empty");
    item = -1;
  } else {
    item = q->items[q->front];
    q->front++;
    if (q->front > q->rear) {
      printf("Resetting queue \n");
      q->front = q->rear = -1;
    }
  }
  return item;
}

void print(struct adjlistnode* n) {
    while (n != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", n->dest);
        n = n->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void freeLL(struct adjlistnode* head) {
   struct adjlistnode* tmp;

   while (head != NULL)
    {
       tmp = head;
       head = head->next;
       free(tmp);
    }

}

void freeGraph(struct Graph* G) {
    for (int i = 0; i < G->vertices; i++) {
        freeLL(G->array[i].head);
    }
    free(G->array);
    free(G->visited);
    free(G);
}

void connect(struct adjlistnode* n, struct adjlistnode* n2, char name[], char name2[]) {
    // printf("in here, name is %s name2 is %s\n", name, name2);
    struct adjlistnode* temp;
    struct adjlistnode* temp2;
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    while (n->next != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(n->next->dest, name2) > 0) {
            temp = n->next;
            n->next = makenode(name2);
            n->next->next = temp;
            count = 1;
            break;
        } else if (strcmp(n->next->dest, name2) < 0) {
            n = n->next;
            continue;
        } else if (strcmp(n->next->dest, name2) == 0) {
            return;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        n->next = makenode(name2);
    }
    while (n2->next != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(n2->next->dest, name) > 0) {
            temp2 = n2->next;
            n2->next = makenode(name);
            n2->next->next = temp2;
            count2 = 1;
            break;
        } else if (strcmp(n2->next->dest, name) < 0) {
            n2 = n2->next;
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (count2 == 0) {
        n2->next = makenode(name);
    }
}

void freequeue(struct queue* queue) {
    free(queue);
}

void printQueue(struct queue* q) {
  int i = q->front;

  if (isEmpty(q)) {
    printf("Queue is empty");
  } else {
    printf("\nQueue contains ");
    for (i = q->front; i < q->rear + 1; i++) {
      printf("%d ", q->items[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}


void bfs(struct Graph* graph, char name[]) {
    int num;
    struct queue* queue = createqueue();
    for (int i = 0; i < graph->vertices; i++) {
        if (strcmp(graph->array[i].head->dest, name) == 0) {
            num = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("here in bfs\n");
    graph->visited[num] = 1;
    enqueue(queue, num, graph->vertices);
    printQueue(queue);

    while(!isEmpty(queue)) {
        printQueue(queue);
        int currentvert = dequeue(queue);
        // printf("after this\n");
        printf("%s ", graph->array[currentvert].head->dest);

        while (graph->array[currentvert].head != NULL) {
            printf("in bfs nested loop\n");
            char n[100];
            strcpy(n, graph->array[currentvert].head->dest);
            for (int i = 0; i < graph->vertices; i++) {
                if (strcmp(n, graph->array[currentvert].head->dest) == 0) {
                    num = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            int adjvert = num;

            if (graph->visited[adjvert] == 0) {
                graph->visited[adjvert] = 1;
                enqueue(queue, adjvert, graph->vertices);
            }
            graph->array[currentvert].head = graph->array[currentvert].head->next;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    freequeue(queue);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[argc + 1]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE* file2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");

    int x;
    char name[100];
    char name2[100];
    fscanf(file, "%d\n", &x);
    struct Graph* graph = creategraph(x);

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        fscanf(file, "%s\n", name);
        graph->array[i].head = makenode(name);
    }

    while (fscanf(file, "%s %s\n", name, name2) != EOF) {
        int num1, num2;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            if (strcmp(graph->array[i].head->dest, name) == 0) {
                num1 = i;
                continue;
            }
            if (strcmp(graph->array[i].head->dest, name2) == 0) {
                num2 = i;
                continue; 
            }
        }
        connect(graph->array[num1].head, graph->array[num2].head, name, name2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        print(graph->array[i].head);
    }

    while (fscanf(file2, "%s\n", name) != EOF) {
        bfs(graph, name);
    }

    // for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    //     print(graph->array[i].head);
    // }
    freeGraph(graph);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What is the [minimal data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that produces the leak?

Comment: Did you try debugging with optimizations disabled, i.e. `-O0`?